# Ci session cookie copied to different browser

Tags: codeigniter

Logged in chrome browser , now copying the ci session cookie to Firefox browser , I am able to login , without entrying the username and password.how can I stop such behaviour in codeigniter

Comment: I think, this is not a real world threat, you need to log in at least once. It's not like you get that session cookie if you have not logged in before in one of the browsers you use

Comment: I know it's not real world threat, but still don't allow user to login using ci_session cookie in different browser which is used in other browser

Comment: set and compare user_agent(): https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata